# Undeclared identifier in showAlert method

Tags: ios, xcode

Am getting numerous error in my showAlert method which don't make sense to me. Have created my title local variable, but still get undeclared identifier error messages. Have commented out the error messages after the code.

Can you help?

Here is the code in the BullseyeViewController.m file:

```
- (IBAction)showAlert
{
    int difference = abs(targetValue - currentValue);
    int points =  100 - difference;
    score += points;

    NSString *title;
    if (difference == 0) {
        title = @"Perfect!";
        points += 100;
    } else if (difference < 5) {
        if (difference == 1) {
            points += 50;
        }
        title = @"You almost had it!";
    } else if (difference < 10) {
        title = @"Pretty good!";
    } else {
       title = @"Not even close...";
    }


    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %d points", points];  //    unused variable 'message'
    }


    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:title // use of undeclared identifier 'title'
                          message:message
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" // Expected ';' after top level    declarator 2 
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alertView show]; // Missing '[' at start of message send expression


} // Expected external declaration
```

Comment: The '}' after NSString message?

Comment: Yes, the '}' after NSString message was causing all the problems, thanks. 'Title' is a local variable, not an ivar.

Answer (score 1):

you have one curly bracket too much after the message declaration. just remove it.
thats why the variable title is out of scope.

```
- (IBAction)showAlert
{
    ...

    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"You scored %d points", points];  //    unused variable 'message'
    // REMOVE THIS => }


    UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                          initWithTitle:title // use of undeclared identifier 'title'
                          message:message
                          delegate:self 
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" // Expected ';' after top level    declarator 2 
                          otherButtonTitles: nil];

    [alertView show]; // Missing '[' at start of message send expression


} // Expected external declaration
```